# login: login: Could not determine audit condition

Tags: macos, terminal, macos-sierra

I got stuck with the process completion window of Mac terminal. Restarting Terminal, rebooting Mac, nothing working. Whenever I open terminal it shows the same window and I cannot write on it. **How to resolve it**?

[image]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I recently had my MacOS (Sierra 10.12.3) Terminal greet me with ..

```
   login: Could not determine audit condition

   [Process completed]
```

.. after I messed with my usr/bin permissions.

After a lot of trial and error I fixed it by deleting the FILE (not folder) called 'login', which is in /usr/bin.

I make a point to stress that it's not a folder but a file, because prior to Sierra there *was* a folder called **usr/bin/login**, whose deletion fixed some permission issues causing Terminal failures.

On MacOS Sierra the folder has been removed, but deleting the 'login' file (or moved it someplace else) solved my problem, and my machine works fine.

Good luck!

Comment: I fixed the issue in same way you did, but i was a little bit confused, if any side effect could arise. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The other answer to this problem fairly bizarre and the solution to this is most certainly not to just go and delete the login file.

Not only is the directory where that file is found protected by System Integrity Protection preventing this from being possible as described, but the login file is not just some auto-regenerated plist file, its a mach-o executable and the code that is needed to log any user in.

The issue is not even login causing a problem as indicated by the error message login is running into that mentions audit aka the Basic Security Module which logs security events and also takes actions for example terminating a process or even halting the OS should some variable occur.

The solution is to simply repair permissions. Since Disk Utility includes that option in a way that addresses this issue you'll have to sort of trick the Terminal into this:

1. Go to the Preferences page in Terminal
2. Find the "Shells open with:" item on the General tab
3. Select the "Command (complete path)" option
4. Enter the following in the space provided:

> > sudo /usr/sbin/diskutil resetUserPermissions /dev/disk1s1 501

5. Open a new Terminal tab or window
6. Enter your password and allow the process to complete
7. Open a new tab or window to verify success

Note: You'll need to enter the correct mount point which may not be /dev/disk1s1 and the correct UID for your current user which may not be 501 but these are both the most likely possibilities.

Comment: This seems like the right idea but does it fix permissions on the /usr/bin/login file somehow? I don't know what resetUserPermissions really does, but it doesn't seem like it fixes permissions in /usr

Answer (score 1):

Deleting usr/bin/login worked for me as well but it did have side effects (I later noticed that some ENV variables were missing that were presumably dependent on the login file).
The problem was coming from the permissions So I did the following:

- renamed the login file to sth else so terminal would work again
- started another terminal instance
- reverted the name change (and kept the working terminal instance open)
- in the working terminal:

  - "sudo chown root:wheel /usr/bin/login"
  - "sudo chmod 4755 /usr/bin/login"

Then it all went back to normal.

Answer (score -1):

This reply is in reference to Marcus Eckert's permission fix below....

First - if you are running High Sierra, you need to disable SIP in Recovery Mode (restart with Cmd-R). The open terminal and run csrutil disable. You can then restart and log into your normal admin account. Now you can rename login file to loginOLD, open an operational terminal window, revert the filename to login, and run the two sudo commands.

Once you get login fixed, be sure to restart Cmd-R, then open terminal and enable SIP by running csrutil enable. After a restart, you can verify by opening Terminal and running csrutil status.

Once I had sudo working properly and disabled SIP your sudo commands worked. I 
... renamed login to loginOLD
... opened an operational terminal window
... renamed loginOLD back to login
... ran the two sudo commands
... verified success by opening a new operational terminal window.
... restarted with CMD-R and re-enabled SIP
... restarted and logged in as my normal admin
... opened Terminal, got a operational window, ran csrutil status, go "System Integrity Protection status: enabled."

Thanks Marcus

Comment: can't run the sudo even with the system integrity protection disabled

Answer (score -1):

You need delete the file "login", it is not the path below.

1. Open "Finder"
2. Open "Go To Folder"
3. Type "/usr/bin/login"
4. Delete the file "login".
5. Open again the "terminal", you can see that the terminal it is open correctly.

Answer (score -1):

I just had this issue and I did:

- navigate to /usr/bin/login and rename login to loginOLD
- open Terminal/Preferences/General/Shells opens with and this command:

  sudo /usr/sbin/diskutil resetUserPermissions /dev/disk1s4 501
- new shell/tab and it asks for your password
- YES! Good news!!! Terminal goes:

  Ready to reset user permissions on disk1s4 laosElCapitan

Started verify/repair permissions on disk1s4 laosElCapitan

Hope this helps others!

LAO

Answer (score -1):

Many thanks to all for the preparatory work. Here is the summary and some changes for MacOS 10.13.

**MacOS 10.13 High Sierra Solution for**

**Terminal: Could not determine audit condition
AND
Incorrect access rights to hard disks that cannot be changed**

1. navigate to /usr/bin/login and rename login to loginOLD
   1.1 If not possible, disable SIP in Recovery Mode (restart with Cmd-R). Then open terminal and run csrutil disable. You can then restart and log into your normal admin account.
2. open Terminal/Preferences/General/Shells opens with and this command:

sudo /usr/sbin/diskutil resetUserPermissions /dev/disk1s1 501 [or your Systemdisk and Admin-Account, fex disk1s2 502]

2.1 if: sudo: /usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set
-> enable root user

2.2 Enable root user

Use Spotlight to find and open directory services, or do the following:

```
In the Finder, select Go to > Go to Folder from the menu bar.
Type or paste /System/Library/CoreServices/Applications/, then press Enter.
Open Directory Services in the window that opens.
```

In the Directory Services window, click the lock icon, then enter an administrator name and password.
To activate the root user, select "Edit" > "Activate root user" in the menu bar. Then enter the desired password. You can then log in as the root user.
To deactivate the root user later , select "Edit" > "Deactivate root user". 3.

3. log out from admin, log in as root

3.1 Open Terminal/Preferences/General/Shells opens with and this command:

sudo /usr/sbin/diskutil resetUserPermissions /dev/disk1s1 501 [or your Systemdisk and Admin-Account, fex disk1s2 502]

If it asks for your password, type password in.

**YES!** Terminal is functioning properly.

4. log out as root, log in as admin
5. Deactivate root-user (Directory Services, select "Edit" > "Deactivate root user")
6. hard disk utility: ececute "first aid" for not yet properly assigned hard disks.
7. open the information window of the affected hard disk and reassign rights.
8. Enable SIP in Recovery Mode (restart with Cmd-R). Then open terminal and run csrutil enable. Restart and log into your normal admin account.

DONE